# In C++, if i have a vector of vector type, what would happen if i do this following: vector_variable.push_back()?

Tags: c++, vector, std

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point2d> > components;
```

Where Point2d is a structure :

```
struct Point2d {
int x;
int y;
};

std::vector<Point2d> tmp;
components.push_back( tmp );// What does this line do?
```

I know the problem is with my understanding of c++ vectors. 
As per my knowledge : In the above code, Components is vector of vector. Inner Vector is of type Point2d. Outer Vector Group of Inner Vector types.

In the above code.. Components.push_back(tmp) do?

Answer (score 1):

The size of `components` is increased by 1. The last element of `components` is a vector of `Point2d`. This vector is copied from `tmp` which was empty. During the `push_back` operation, the vector `components` may need to reallocate storage, which could copy its elements and invalidate iterators to them.

Answer (score 1):

This line *pushes* the `tmp` vector into the end of the vector of vectors `Components`.

`Components` is a `std::vector<std::vector<Point2d> >`, that is at every index of `Components`, you can access a `std::vector<Point2d>`.

That is, if you `push_back` a `std::vector<Point2d>` (`tmp`) into an empty `Components`, the first element of the `Components` would be a copy of the `tmp` vector.

You can access this vector using `Components[0]`.